# How to update data to a div without deleting it and remaking it in a javascript interval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this interval code:

```
const interval = setInterval(function() {
    run();                                                //Load Divs
    $('.parentDiv').remove();                             //Remove Divs
  }, 10000);                                              //Loop in 10 Seconds
```

The issue is that this is NOT SMOOTH at all. Is there a better way to refresh the divs with data than to delete them and remake them?

You can see the current code on this test site https://footballify.net/test/. It is not smooth.

code:

```
//Pull API Data for UTC
var run = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`https://v3.football.api-sports.io/fixtures?date=${isoStr}`, {
        headers: {
            'X-RapidAPI-Host': "v3.football.api-sports.io",
            "X-RapidAPI-Key": "e54f3d3972ca8251c1259694b49948de"
        },
    });
//Parse JSON
const json = (await res.json())?.response;
//Map desiredOrder onto API Call
const ordered = desiredOrder.map((id) => json.filter(({ league }) => league?.id === id));
//Remove any Null Values
const filtered = ordered.filter(e => e.length);

//arrLeagues created to avoid duplicate leagues
let arrLeagues = [];
console.log(filtered)
//Loop through leagues
for (i = 0; i < filtered.length-1; i++) {
   //Loop through games of Leagues
   for (x=0; x<filtered[i].length;x++){
    //Create Parent Div For Data
    let parent = document.createElement("div")
    parent.className = 'parentDiv'
    
    //League Duplication not allowed
    if (arrLeagues.includes(filtered[i][x].league.id)) {

    } else {
    arrLeagues.push(filtered[i][x].league.id)

    //League Name
    let league = document.createElement("div")
    league.className = 'league'
    league.innerHTML = filtered[i][x].league.name + `<img class='flag' src=${filtered[i][x].league.flag}>`
    parent.appendChild(league)
    }

    //Home Container
    let child1 = document.createElement("div")
    child1.className = 'childDiv'

    //Game Status
    let gameStatus = document.createElement("div")
    gameStatus.className = 'status'
    gameStatus.innerHTML = filtered[i][x].fixture.status.short
    parent.appendChild(gameStatus)

    //Home Name
    let homeTeamName = document.createElement("div")
    homeTeamName.className = 'team1'
    homeTeamName.innerHTML = filtered[i][x].teams.home.name
    parent.appendChild(homeTeamName)
  
    //Home Score
    let homeTeamScore = document.createElement("div")
    homeTeamScore.className = 'score1'

    
    parent.appendChild(homeTeamScore)

    //Away Container
    let child2 = document.createElement("div")
    child2.className = 'childDiv'

    //Away Name
    let awayTeamName = document.createElement("div")
    awayTeamName.className = 'team2'
    awayTeamName.innerHTML = filtered[i][x].teams.away.name
    parent.appendChild(awayTeamName)

    //Away Score
    let awayTeamScore = document.createElement("div")
    awayTeamScore.className = 'score2'

    parent.appendChild(awayTeamScore)

    //Push all Data to DOM
    document.querySelector('.parentContainer').appendChild(parent);
  


    if (String(filtered[i][x].fixture.status.short) === 'NS') {
        homeTeamScore.innerHTML = 0
        homeTeamScore.classList.add('hide')
        awayTeamScore.innerHTML = 0
        awayTeamScore.classList.add('hide')

    } else if (String(filtered[i][x].fixture.status.short) === 'CANC') {
        homeTeamScore.classList.add('hide')
        homeTeamScore.innerHTML = 0
        awayTeamScore.classList.add('hide')
        awayTeamScore.innerHTML = 0
        gameStatus.innerHTML = 'NA'
    } else if (String(filtered[i][x].fixture.status.short) === 'FT') {
        homeTeamScore.classList.remove('hide')
        homeTeamScore.innerHTML = filtered[i][x].goals.home
        awayTeamScore.classList.remove('hide')
        awayTeamScore.innerHTML = filtered[i][x].goals.away
    } else if (String(filtered[i][x].fixture.status.short) === 'HT') {
        homeTeamScore.classList.remove('hide')
        homeTeamScore.classList.add('live')
        homeTeamScore.innerHTML = filtered[i][x].goals.home
        awayTeamScore.classList.remove('hide')
        awayTeamScore.classList.add('live')
        gameStatus.classList.add('live')
        awayTeamScore.innerHTML = filtered[i][x].goals.away
    } else if (String(filtered[i][x].fixture.status.short) == '1H') {
        homeTeamScore.classList.remove('hide')
        homeTeamScore.classList.add('live')
        homeTeamScore.innerHTML = filtered[i][x].goals.home
        awayTeamScore.classList.remove('hide')
        awayTeamScore.classList.add('live')
        awayTeamScore.innerHTML = filtered[i][x].goals.away
        gameStatus.classList.add('live')
        gameStatus.innerHTML = filtered[i][x].fixture.status.elapsed + "′"
    } else if (String(filtered[i][x].fixture.status.short) == 'ET') {
        homeTeamScore.classList.remove('hide')
        homeTeamScore.classList.add('live')
        homeTeamScore.innerHTML = filtered[i][x].goals.home
        awayTeamScore.classList.remove('hide')
        awayTeamScore.classList.add('live')
        awayTeamScore.innerHTML = filtered[i][x].goals.away
        gameStatus.classList.add('live')
        gameStatus.innerHTML = filtered[i][x].fixture.status.elapsed + "′"
    } else if (String(filtered[i][x].fixture.status.short) == '2H') {
        homeTeamScore.classList.remove('hide')
        homeTeamScore.classList.add('live')
        homeTeamScore.innerHTML = filtered[i][x].goals.home
        awayTeamScore.classList.remove('hide')
        awayTeamScore.classList.add('live')
        awayTeamScore.innerHTML = filtered[i][x].goals.away
        gameStatus.classList.add('live')
        gameStatus.innerHTML = filtered[i][x].fixture.status.elapsed + "′"
    
    } else {}

    //If Home Wins
    if (filtered[i][x].teams.home.winner == true) {
        homeTeamName.classList.add('winner')
        awayTeamName.classList.add('loser')
        homeTeamScore.classList.add('winner')
        awayTeamScore.classList.add('loser')

  } else if (filtered[i][x].teams.away.winner == true) {
      //If Away Wins
        awayTeamName.classList.add('winner')
        homeTeamName.classList.add('loser')
        awayTeamScore.classList.add('winner')
        homeTeamScore.classList.add('loser')
      //Match Not Started or  Cancelled
  } else if (filtered[i][x].fixture.status.short == 'NS' || 'CANC'){
    homeTeamName.classList.add('winner')
    homeTeamScore.classList.add('winner')
    awayTeamScore.classList.add('winner')
    awayTeamName.classList.add('winner')

  } else {
      //Draw
        homeTeamName.classList.add('loser')
        awayTeamName.classList.add('loser')
        homeTeamScore.classList.add('loser')
        awayTeamScore.classList.add('loser')
    }



    }
  }     

};

run();
```

so it is a fetch of data along with appending the data do dom

Comment: What does `run` do, does it have async fetch of data inside ?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're trying to accomplish here. I know that you are trying to refresh the data, so I suggest simply changing the content of the div by doing something like so: `$('.parentDiv').html('new data here')`.

Comment: @cesarepolonara yes, i just posted my script.js above

Comment: @sirfire I have no idea what to put in the 'new data here' section perhaps with the edited code you could tell?

Comment: @AKaz20005 Ah, now that I see your `run()` code, I know a bit more about this. To be clear, here is what's happening: You are creating a DIV and putting the data in it initially. Then, every 10 seconds, you delete that DIV and create the new one with the new data. Instead, you could just make a DIV in the HTML with an ID, and edit that same DIV every 10 seconds.

Comment: That's the problem, run() is asynchronous, so you delete the div before the new one is ready. Just do `run().then(_ => $('.parentDiv').remove();)`

Comment: @sirfire could you put a answer up using random variables because I don't know how to edit this, I will mark correct.

Comment: @AKaz20005 asking the same question over and over is a good way to get a question ban. If you're not getting the answer you want, or are not understanding the answers being given, edit your question or ask for more detail in the comments. Don't spam questions.

Comment: @CesarePolonara When I put that in the interval the div stays deleted and does not show up?

Comment: Then you have to place the `remove` action inside the `run` function, and execute it just before to write the new data. That way it will be smooth.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
const interval = setInterval(async function() {
    if ($('.parentDiv').length) { // Check if the parent div exists
        $('.parentDiv').remove(); // Remove the div
    }
    await run(); // Fire the run function to create a new div with new data
}, 10000);
```

## Edit:

I think the problem with my above answer is that there is still a delay: The time that it takes for your code to both get the data from your API and build your div with all of its child elements. With this in mind, try deleting the div within the `run()` function right before a new div is created. This way, all of the processing can be done while the old data is still visible. Try this:

**Interval code:**

```
const interval = setInterval(async function() {
    await run();
});
```

**Run function:**

```
$('.parentDiv').remove(); // Remove the old div
//Push all Data to DOM
document.querySelector('.parentContainer').appendChild(parent);
```

Comment: It works the same as my initial program it is not smooth :(

Comment: @AKaz20005 Check my edits